# Why do I get this argument error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error:

```
ArgumentError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #15 raised:

No association found for name `genre'. Has it been defined yet?
```

Line 15 is: `<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(current_user.profile) %>`

Genre has a has_and_belongs_to_many association with Profile.

I have this in my routes:

```
resources :profiles
resources :genres
```

This is my genres controller(I'm trying to use [this autocomplete field](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) with a set of prepopulated genres:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def index
  respond_with(@genres = Genre.search(params[:q]))
end
```

And this is my Genre model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles

scope :search, lambda {|q| where("name LIKE ?', "%q%') }
```

This is in my application.js:

```
$("#genre_field").tokenInput(genres_path);
```

So why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Seeing as you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` shouldn't that be `genres`?

Comment: Since the error occurs when you call current_user.profile the problem is probably somewhere in the Profile model. My guess would be where you associate to genre. If you used has_and_belongs_to_many like you said, make sure it is plural

Comment: ahhh yeah that was it  :)  thanks DanneManne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` you should pluralize `genre`.